# Trying to guess the form of an expression

Tags: calculus, functions

So I'm trying to guess an expression/formula $f(N)$ (I'm pretty sure it's a type of radical expression) so that:

- $N=3$ gives $f(3)=\sqrt{3}(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$

  $N=4$ gives $f(4)=\sqrt{3}(2+3/\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$.

For only $2$ values there are a lot of expressions that could fit the data, however I don't know what the value is for $N=5,6,7...$ exactly but I do know them to a pretty high accuracy ($9+$ decimals) namely:

- $f(5) \approx 13.0730010026585$

  $f(6) \approx 16.4039895781353$

  $f(7) \approx 19.2521746691918$ and so on.

So I'm wondering how can I guess the exact form of the expression that fits these data? I tried fitting a polynomial to it, but that doesn't go through the exact values of my data for higher $N$ and it should be a simple expression that goes through the data exactly which leads me to believe the expression is probably a radical (something that looks like $N^{7/3}(N-2)$ or something).

Comment: How do those expressions depend on $\;n\;$ ??

Comment: So I'm trying to guess an expression/formula f(N) that for N=3 gives f(3)=$\displaystyle\sqrt{3}(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ and for N=4 f(4)=$\displaystyle\sqrt{3}(2+3/\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ I also know the value f(5), f(6), f(7), ... to a high accuracy (9 decimals) but not exactly. Now how do I go about and finding this expression? ( I already know it should probally be a short radical, something that looks like N^(7/3)*(N-2) or something

Comment: This question is not clear. What data points are you talking about?

Comment: Why do you know the exact values for $N=3,4$ and not others ? Give us a clue where these numbers are coming from.

Comment: Because the problem I'm working on is a complicated N particle quantum physics problem that I can solve exactly for N=3 and N=4 particles and only numerically for higher N

Comment: @Spacer: so what could be the reason why those radicals appear ? Are $1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3$ related to diagonals in a cube ? Have you investigated $\sqrt3(a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3)$ with $a,b,c$ rationals ?

Comment: Yes the particles are configured so that they are in their lowest energy, for N=3 this is a triangle and N=4 it's a tetrahedron. For higher N the geometrical shape is not so simple, but it is similar to that of a crystal. However I'm not sure if this information is even needed to answer the question as I'm just trying to find an expression that fits some data points.

Comment: Are you kidding ? With no hint on the problem formulation, one can search forever with any functional expression. Are there reasons to see cube roots instead of square roots or other powers ? Are there reasons to believe in algebraic numbers ? Is there a reason to have three terms ...

Answer (score 0):

How about $$\sqrt{3}\left(n-2) + \frac{n-1}{2}\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}\right).$$

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: @B. Goddard Your formula, unfortunately, doesn't fit the data the OP has now given